# If statement with or in C

Tags: c

I am trying to make an if statement that would create an error message if the user does not input the values of 1 or 2. I imagine it would look something like

```
if (type != 1 or 2) {
    printf ("Enter numbers 1 or 2");
}
```

I know the or part in between the 1 and the 2 of the if statement wont work but what will? Thanks!

Btw: this is written in C.

Comment: this site expects you to post code not some untested guess.

Comment: BTW: each possible value needs to be checked separately.  so a statement like: `if( 1 != type && 2 != type )`  assuming that type is a numeric.  if type is a char, then `if( '1' != type && '2' != type )`   Note: 'type' is kind of a iffy variable name suggest using something more akin to the context of the problem being solved.  For instance if the problem were about automobiles, then the name might be: 'carType'

Answer (score 3):

Even though you'd verbally express it as "not 1 or 2", programatically you'd use an `and` instead because it's only if neither values match up that you'd display your error prompt.

```
if (type != 1 && type != 2){
    printf ("Enter numbers 1 or 2");
}
```

Using an `or` would cause issues. If you entered a `2`, the first statement is true and the if statement result would trigger.

Note: I am not factoring in what data type the `type` variable is.